# Mount a host file as a data volume in docker

Tags: docker

I am following this docker user guide: [Managing Data in Containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

It seem to be a error at "Mount a Host File as a Data Volume" part,

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -it -v ~/.bash_history:/.bash_history ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I test it in my mac version docker, it should be like this:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -it -v ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I am not sure if am I correct about this.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score -1):

You can't use -v option with relative path. You need to use absolute path instead:

```
sudo docker run --rm -it -v /home/<your_user>/.bash_history:/.bash_history ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: I don't think the original question is showing a relative path, is it?

Comment: @SanderVerhagen Isn't ~ relative to the user that issues the command? In OP's case that would be root.

Comment: `~` on your command line is almost certainly expanded to `/home/<your_user>` before it ever hits Docker. So, `~` isn't really a relative path. `./something` or `../else` I'd call relative paths; different thing.